# Display only one list item at the center of the <div> with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying out a vertical ticker that displays a few text list items one after the other, but I need some help in positioning them.

You'll see a web ticker with two items. To display only one item at a time, I have to set 'overflow:hidden' in #tickerContainer.

However, the text in the ticker is not being positioned at the center of the ticker(As you see it is sitting at the bottom).

Also, when I remove 'overflow:hidden' from #tickerContainer, which is the whole ticker moving away from the top of the page?

Please help me fix this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/nodovitt/NYhY4/2/

```
<div id="tickerContainer">
    <ul id="ticker" class="js-hidden">
        <li class="news-item">Item Number 1</li>
        <li class="news-item">Item Number 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery function:

```
<script>
function tick() {
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(1000, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(1000);
    });
}
setInterval(function () {
    tick()
}, 2000);
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
#tickerContainer {
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:15px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px black;
    color:#2B7CD8;
    font-size:50px;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.news-item {
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    font-style:oblique;
}
#ticker li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/NYhY4/3/

Comment: awesome thanks! Can you post that as an answer so that I accept and close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer as requested by OP

Add this css to your `#ticker`

```
#ticker {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

**NOTE** The line-height will always have to be the height of the `#tickerContainer`

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/NYhY4/3/

Comment: Very nice tweak! Doesn't depend on font size

Answer (score 2):

You haven't put any specifications on your ticker id. So something like this http://jsfiddle.net/NYhY4/10/

```
#ticker {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
padding-top:20px;
height:55px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ticker li {
    list-style-type:none;
    position: relative;
    bottom:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the current item being hidden by seemingly "nothing" (the blank part of li box above the text) so I used this approach:

1. Remove the margins from the '#ticker'
2. set '#ticker' padding-top (.5em worked best for me)
3. set '#ticker li' padding-bottom to push the next item out of view (I used '1em' to be safe but '.5em' worked too)

The words didn't look perfectly centered so

1. set '#ticker li' line-height to '1em'

   `#ticker {
       margin: 0;
       padding-top: .5em;
   }`

   `#ticker li{
       line-height: 1em;
       padding-bottom: 1em;
       list-style-type: none;
   }`

http://jsfiddle.net/JvuKU/2/

*Note* This depends on the font-size of the '#tickerContainer'. If you change the height or font-size of the '#tickerContainer', just adjust the values of '#ticker' padding-top and '#ticker li' padding-bottom.